# Image margin not changing. Possibly due to my javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, margin

So my site basically shows the percent of strikes you have "thrown" (baseball).
I have set my JavaScript to display a gif if the percent is above 60.
However, the image seems to be ignoring the css I have set for the image. Any solutions?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <title>Javascript Time</title>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testingJS.css">
        <script src="testingJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Javascript</h2>

        <p id="change">Strike Percent Counter</p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Ball" class="btn" onclick="throwBall()"></p>
        <p><input type="button" value ="Strike" class="btn" onclick="throwStrike()"></p>

        <p>Percent of Strikes:</p>
        <strong><p id="percent"></p></strong> 

        <img id="winner" src="">

    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
p, H2{
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#percent{
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto auto auto;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-emphasis: 5px;
    border: 7px solid gold;
}

.btn{
    font-size: 29px;
    float: center;
}

#winner{
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
}

body{
    background-image: url("http://static.zoonar.com/img/www_repository3/db/3a/39/10_4baf1185c09f28bcbe957e13a0c34fca.jpg");
}
```

And my JavaScript:

```
var ball = 0;
var strike = 0;

function throwBall(){
    ball++;
    var percent = strike / (ball + strike);
    var round = percent.toFixed(2) * 100;
    document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = round + "%";

    if (round <= 60){
        document.getElementById("winner").src = "";
    }
}

function throwStrike(){
    strike++;
    var percent = strike / (ball + strike);
    var round = percent.toFixed(2) * 100;
    document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = round + "%";
     if (round > 60){
        document.getElementById("winner").src =     "https://media.giphy.com/media/NxA9Wmq8ISblK/giphy.gif";
    }
}
```

I'm doing this solely out of practicing my skills and have been stuck on this for sometime. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a fiddle? - https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What is the image doing, and what is the intended result?  Is it safe to assume you want it to display in the center of the screen?

Comment: Try using fix margin on `#winner` and see what will happen.

Comment: The image is displaying on the right side and I am wanting it to display in the middle. Using a fixed margin seems to be working, while auto does not?

Comment: Wrap the image in a `<p>` tag like everything else

Comment: @xkcd149 that worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to display element in the middle, set `width` property to fit width,  `display` property to `block` and `margin:0 auto;`

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7vuzwx8z/